# "Blasting down the doors"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Every cop in this city is gonna be ***blasting down these doors***
>   after what you did.

What does the marked phrase mean? Is it something like "break the door down"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, it means the police will *blow open* the door with explosives (or, at least, great force).

Figuratively, it means the police will quickly come to arrest them, using *every means at their disposal* (including, presumably, explosives or great force).

The figurative meaning is more likely in most contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, yes!

> Blast:
>
> To explode or destroy something or someone with explosives, or to break through or hit something with a similar, very strong force:
>
> > A tunnel was to be blasted through the mountains.
> >     They heard the guns blasting away all night.
> >     figurative Their latest album blasted (its way) up the charts (= moved very quickly because of its popularity).

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blast)